# android thread not running

Tags: android

I am trying to insert some data into the database if the app is running for its first time, so I create a progressbar and a thread to do that ,but the thread seems not running and the progressbar just keep showing, can anyone explain why, thx

my code:

```
public class HDtvs extends Activity implements Runnable {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private Button likebutton;
    private ImageButton about;
    private ChannelDB mDB;
    private ListView channellist;
    private Cursor c;
    private ProgressDialog d;
    private String channelS_TABLE;

    @Override    
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        likebutton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.share);
        about =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.about);
        channellist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Channel);

        if (tabIsExist(channelS_TABLE) != true){
        d=new ProgressDialog(HDtvs.this);
        d.setMessage("由于您第一次使用，本程序正在创建数据库，请稍后···");
        d.show();
        /* 启动另一个Thread，运行run() */
        Thread thread = new Thread(HDtvs.this);
        thread.start();
        }else{
            filldata();
            Log.d(this.toString(),"database exist");
        }

    }


    public void filldata(){
        mDB = new ChannelDB(this);

        String[] columns = {mDB.KEY_ID, mDB.KEY_POSTER, mDB.KEY_CHANNEL, mDB.KEY_PATH, mDB.KEY_DBLINK};
        String   table   = mDB.channelS_TABLE;

        c = mDB.getHandle().query(table, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

        startManagingCursor(c);

        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.channelview,
                c,
                new String[] {mDB.KEY_POSTER, mDB.KEY_CHANNEL, mDB.KEY_DBLINK},
                new int[] {R.id.poster, R.id.channel, R.id.douban});

        adapter.setViewBinder(new ChannelViewBinder());

        channellist.setAdapter(adapter);

        channellist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                c.moveToPosition(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(HDtvs.this,Showlist.class);
                Bundle bunde = new Bundle();
                bunde.putString("path",mDB.KEY_PATH);
                bunde.putString("cname",mDB.KEY_CHANNEL);
                bunde.putString("dblink",mDB.KEY_DBLINK);
                /* 将Bundle对象assign给Intent */
                intent.putExtras(bunde);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }); 
    }
    private Handler handler = new Handler()
    {
      @Override 
      public void handleMessage(Message msg)
      { 
        d.dismiss();

      }
    };

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
      try
      {
          mDB.Reset();

          insert some data

          handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);          
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is easier to use the AsyncTask for that:
Create a new inner class which extends from AsyncTask:

```
  private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {...
```

In the AsyncTask-Method `doInBackground` you can put your Database code.

Simply start the AsyncTask with `new MyTask().execute();` from e.g. onCreate.
If you want to have a ProgressBar you need to take a look at the `onPreExecute, onPostExecute and onProgressUpdate` Methods.

Comment: Your answer is very inspiring,well, I tried Asynctask before, but gave up later because when the asynctask is running,the screen is just black and showing nothing at all, and I think that is not good.Any Ideas to solve that?

Comment: Coz I am now putting this procedure in my Splash screen and I would like to have a more user-friendly splash, but the splash image just won't show after I used this asynctask,plz help,thx

Comment: Sure: Just build your SplashScreen in the onCreate-Method and then execute your AsyncTask. In onPostExecute you can fire up the Intent for the next Activity.

Comment: Thx,man. But I still get a curious black screen after the splash screen and before the main activity. I posted my code here,maybe you would like to check it out for me . thx
http://www.anddev.org/post107025.html#p107025

Comment: I don't see what why you have this Thread in your onCreate Method. All you have to do is start the AsyncTask in onCreate and start the new Activity in onPostExecute. Waiting in the AsyncTask: synchronized (this) {
      wait(2000);
  }

Comment: ,Well,that's coz I thought if the table exist then the splash screen won't show but I want it to show up before main activity for at least some seconds so I kinda find a solution like that

Comment: You can do all this in AsyncTask. Just say for example if table exist do you querys and if not wait 2 seconds in the doinBackground-Method.